# tensorflow using tf.train.string_input_producer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tf.train.string_input_producer to read data from tfRecord file. I suppose it create a queue and pipeline and the data will automatically loaded and feed into my model. However, it stuck at the first batch, and show this exception:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs

my tfrecord was made by tf.train.SequenceExample, instead of tf.train.Example, which don't have clear documentation in the official guide.

here is code snapshot to reproduce my problem. (I believe my problem come from the queue initializing or sth. because it seems that the whole pipeline is hang up)

```
from config.config import get_config

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
config = get_config()

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['data0.tfrecord,data1.tfrecord'], 5, capacity=16384)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

(keys, values) = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, config.batch_size)

context_features = {
    "seq_len": tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64),
}
audio_features = {
    "audio": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([config.num_features], dtype=tf.float32),
    "label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([config.num_classes], dtype=tf.float32)
}
audio_list = []
label_list = []
len_list = []

for i in range(config.batch_size):
    print(i)
    context, sequence = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized=values[i],
        context_features=context_features,
        sequence_features=audio_features
    )
    audio = sequence['audio']
    label = sequence['label']
    # seq_len = context['seq_len'][0]
    seq_len = tf.shape(audio)[0]
    audio_list.append(audio)
    label_list.append(label)
    len_list.append(seq_len)

audio_tensor = tf.stack(audio_list)
label_tenor = tf.stack(label_list)
len_tensor = tf.stack(len_list)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    for i in range(3):
        x, y, z = sess.run([audio_tensor, label_tenor, len_tensor])
        print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init2)
```

Variabes (num_epochs or capacity) inside tf.train.string_input_producer() are local variables. You have to initialize them with local variable initializer as shown above.

Let me know if this helped.